# How can i select multiple values from HTML <td></td>block using symfony/dom-crawler in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to crawl data from a page using symfony dom-crawler what data i want i can show them all in a array but i need to store them in a database.[it is the pages html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSVi9.jpg)

[Here is my controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnumC.jpg)
[Here is my out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8I4Z.jpg). In main page inside  you can see value 18, 4 and 35, 3 i need these values to store them in database so how can i do it??.` public function numbers()
    {
        $url = "https://www.lotteryinformation.us/apps/freq-chart.php?state=FL&game=MUPB&tb_state=&tb_links=&tb_country=US&tb_lang=0&adsurl=&tbsite=&d=.";
        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);

```
    $tr_elements = $crawler->filterXPath('//body/center/table/tr/td');
    // iterate over filter results
    foreach ($tr_elements as  $content)
    {
        $tds = array();
        // create crawler instance for result
        $crawler = new Crawler($content);

        foreach ($crawler->filter('tr[valign="middle"]') as  $node) {
            $crawler = new Crawler($node);
            foreach ($crawler->filter('td[class="td0"]') as  $node)
            {
                // extract the value
                 $tds[] = $node->nodeValue;
                //my code
            }
            foreach ($crawler->filter('td[class="td0"]')->eq(2) as  $node)
            {
                // extract the value
                $tds[] = $node->nodeValue;
                //my code
            }

        }
        dd($tds);
        $rows[] = $tds;

    }

   dd($rows);
}`
```

Comment: Please don't share code in images, rather copy it to your question

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Comment: @RossWilson i know how to store them in database but i want to select the numbers together like 18,4 and 35,3 these 2 will go to 2 rows in database.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the question. In that case, as Nico pointed out, can you add the code to your question instead of the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
Well i have solved the problem by doing the code this way ` public function numbers()
{
    $url = "https://www.lotteryinformation.us/apps/freq-chart.php?state=FL&game=MUPB&tb_state=&tb_links=&tb_country=US&tb_lang=0&adsurl=&tbsite=&d=.";

    $client = new Client();


    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);

    $tr_elements = $crawler->filterXPath('//body/center/table/tr/td');
    // iterate over filter results
    foreach ($tr_elements as  $content)
    {
        $tds = array();

        // create crawler instance for result
        $crawler = new Crawler($content);
        //iterate again
        /*$links_count =$crawler->filter('tr[valign="middle"]')->count();
        return $links_count;*/
        foreach ($crawler->filter('tr[valign="middle"]') as  $node) {
            $crawler = new Crawler($node);
            foreach ($crawler->filter('td[class="td0"]')->eq(0) as  $node)
            {
                $rank = $crawler->filter('td[class="td0"]')->eq(1)->text();
                $tds[] = $rank;
                $hit = $crawler->filter('td[class="td0"]')->eq(2)->text();
                $tds[] = $hit;

                $frequency_table = new FrequencyTable;
                $frequency_table->rank = $rank;
                $frequency_table->hit= $hit;
                $frequency_table->save();

              /* $tds[] = $node->nodeValue;*/
            }
        }
        dd($tds);
    }

}` and it is what exactly i wanted. Thank you.
```